# Is it possible to use REGEXP_LIKE in an if statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is it possible in PL/SQL to do something like this?

```
IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE(string, pattern) THEN
 .... 
END IF;
```

so that if-statement executes when the string does not meet the requirements of the pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's allowed. You `IF` syntax is missing the closing `END IF`:

```
IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE(string, pattern) THEN
    .... 
END IF;
```